# Transparent svg with non-transparent background in css

Tags: css, svg, transparent

I have an SVG inside a div like this

```
<div class="container">
    <svg>...</svg>
</div>
```

with the following scss:

```
svg {
    background-color: black;
    fill: none;
}
```

what I expected was for the SVG to be transparent, with a black fill around it, so that you can see the background color of the container. I can not simply set the fill attribute to the background color, as I don't know what color it will be, beforehand.

Is there a simple solution to have an SVG with no fill attribute but a background color?

---

My SVG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG  Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="_x30_0_x5F_A"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px"y="0px" viewBox="0 0 120 120" style="enable-background:new 0 0 120 
120;" xml:space="preserve">
<path d="..."/>
</svg>
```

Comment: You are using `background-color` and `fill` both? Its a bit Confusing!

Comment: @dippas I added it

Comment: @mohammadusman well, the idea was to fill the inverted SVG, so to say. I wanted to fill everything *but* the SVG area, so that the SVG would be the same color as the container, but with a different background around it.

Comment: You are not making much sense I'm afraid.  Do you mean that you want the `<div class="container">` to be black, but where the SVG is, it is transparent and shows whatever is behind the `<div class="container">`?

Comment: And what do you mean by "an SVG with no fill attribute"?

Comment: Please excuse my late response, I am afraid I had given up on the matter and moved on to something else.

@PaulLeBeau, yes, that is exactly what I wish to do.

Comment: Depending on the browsers you need to support, you should be able to achieve what you want using the `mask` and/or `mask-image` CSS properties.

Comment: I should read into those, then. Thank you very much!